# Java JDBC type conversion (Firebird / Jaybird): check value/type compatibility before using getter or updater ResultSet method?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

If I understand (and test a sample JDBC code; using Jaybird for Firebird) well, even using a proper (= respecting the type mapping) updater method (e.g. `ResultSet.updateString`), or maybe `PreparedStatement` parameter, can bring a "conversion exception".

Is it possible (and is it a good practice) to test before actually working with the result set (e.g. running an updater method) whether the actual Java Type/value can be safely converted to the target SQL data type?

Is the "problem" just one-way? I.e. when converting back from SQL to Java (using getter method), is it guaranteed that the correct getter method will never fail (due to conversion problems)?

My examples (Using Jaybird 3.0.2, JDK1.8):

- I need to update field: `NUMERIC(9,2)`. The corresponding updater is: 
  `ResultSet.updateBigDecimal(int columnIndex, BigDecimal x)`. If I use `x = new BigDecimal("123456789.1234")` (bigger precision and scale), I (logically) get an exception:
  *Exception in thread "main" org.firebirdsql.jdbc.field.TypeConversionException: Error converting to big decimal.*
- I need to update field: `VARCHAR(5)`. The corresponding updater is: `ResultSet.updateString(int columnIndex, String x)`. 
  If I use `x = "123456"` (longer string 6 > 5), I (logically) get an exception: *Exception in thread "main" java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation.*

Is there some general elegant way (not depending on specific type) how to check, whether an actual Java value/object can be "saved" to certain SQL field, other than just trying to run the query and catching the exceptions?

I would like to check the values already in my data editing dialog (before actually running the update query). Simple test "VALUE OK / NOT OK" would be fine (knowing just the target SQL type).

It seems quite difficult for me to find all rules I would have to check "type by type" (i.e. for VARCHAR check string length, for NUMERIC check precision and scale etc. - but what else? or would that be sufficient? for integer and float types no need to check anything?).

I tried to go through the Jaybird source codes but the "conversion process" is very complicated (and type-specific), I could not find the answer myself.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. If you want to know which getters/setters should minimally be supported for a specific SQL type, please consult the JDBC specification, appendix B. If you have a specific conversion error in mind, then demonstrate it with an example, and please specify the Jaybird version you are using, and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Just edited the examples...

Comment: A larger scale will not trigger an error (so `1.1234` will store as `1.12` in a `numeric(9,2)`, it is just if the 'unscaled' value doesn't fit in the storage type (smallint, integer or bigint) that the error is triggered. For a `numeric(9,2)` the underlying storage is an `integer`.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC does not provide anything to 'check' values before you actually set them, so Jaybird doesn't either: setting the value is the check. Exact behaviour is driver dependent, Jaybird attempts to validate on setting values, but other drivers might choose to defer this to the database itself (so the error would only occur on execute).

Normally, you would design your database and pick column types based on your business needs, which should naturally have lead to validation **before** you even try to put it in the database.

If you haven't done that until now, start adding validation to your input forms, by restricting lengths, using things like Hibernate Validator, or the validation of your UI framework.

If you are working with highly dynamic requirements (e.g. user provided queries, etc.), then you should use the features that JDBC does provide to create your own validation: The [`ParameterMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html) of a prepared statement and the [`ResultSetMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) of a result set (also accessible from a prepared statement), specifically the `getPrecision` (and `getScale`) of these objects, or maybe even things like [`DatabaseMetadata.getColumns`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

For a character type, `getPrecision` will indicate the max number of characters, for a `numeric` or `decimal` type you can use the max numbers of digits **before** the decimal point as `precision - scale`.

However, in Jaybird this is not a 100% exact, for example `getPrecision` may return 9 for a `numeric(8,2)` if Jaybird can't identify the underlying column, and Jaybird (and Firebird) will actually allow up to precision 10 with some limitations (that is, unscaled max value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, i.e. 21474836.47 for this type).

As to your second question if using getters could cause a conversion exception: normal cases will not, but for example calling `getInt()` on a `BIGINT` with a value larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` will.